# Have problem when parsing data with JSON Parse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I got problem when parsing JSON from my AJAX. This is my error and the data that I want to parse

[image]

This my code:

```
var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/get_produk_by_eancode";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: url, 
  data: { kodePilihan: kodeBarangPilihan, kodeScala: kodeScala, codecust: 
   codeCustomer }, 
  success: function(result) {
    if(result) { 
        console.log(result);
       obj = $.parseJSON(result);
    }
```

My controller

```
public function get_produk_by_eancode() {
    $eancode = $this->input->post('kodePilihan');
    $kodeScala = $this->input->post('kodeScala');
    $codecust = $this->input->post('codecust');
    $barangPilihan = $this->web_ordering_model->get_produk_by_eancode_page3($eancode, $kodeScala, $codecust)->row_array();
    echo json_encode($barangPilihan);
}
```

My result data from the controller or you can see in picture

```
{"SC01132":"*1038 AR BRU KM","SC01002":"BOX-50 dengan Roda","SC01011":"A-19","brand":"Kiramas","verpacking":12,"List1":"76250.00000000","SC01001":"625050","Free":".00","LastTglProduksi":"1900-01-01 00:00:00.000","PricelistName":"Netto"}
```

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format »» code/errors/data as an image » nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: share your code of Ajax here

Comment: sorry, my bad. you can see the code now.

Comment: What environment you use? I mean Webbrowser type, version, jQuery version etc? Maybe try to Ctrl+F5 to clear cache and set "cache: false" to your ajax request.

Comment: what is environment you mean? i'm on chrome now, as u can see in my screenshoot it say jquery 1.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by this code

```
$.trim()
```

Sorry for my long report, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because what you give to parseJSON is not a string.

First try to add content-type to you AJAX call :

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

Also you can convert your object to a string.

Comment: can you implementation on my code above? tq btw for ur aswer

Comment: Or use `result.toString()` before parsing

Comment: nothing happen when i put content type or data type.. even console log it do nothing

Comment: console.log won't happen if it fails before, did you tried toString ?

Comment: when i use datatype or contenttype, no error show... no console log show. it just nothing.

Comment: Do you really need to parse it ? I think you can go without... It's already parsed

Comment: but, it say undefined when i not parse it. i was check my json in http://json.parser.online.fr/ and it say error to. can u check it for me? please

Comment: Give your console output then

Comment: By the way you should access your data with `result[0].SC01132` for example, because you have an array around !

Comment: i change array result to only one obj. you can see my result bottom of the question. or you can see my console here https://imgur.com/jEYzHUG

Comment: is engine can make this happen? the error? because the hosting that i use got problem an must reinstall everything. and this error show after that..

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/get_produk_by_eancode";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: url,
  dataType: "json", //changes
  data: ({ kodePilihan: kodeBarangPilihan, kodeScala: kodeScala, codecust: codeCustomer }), 
  success: function(result) {
    if(result) { 
       console.log(result);
       var obj = JSON.parse(result); //changes
       console.log(obj); //changes
    }
  }
```

Comment: i try this, but nothing hapen when i add data type json.. even console log do nothing.